# React Native move navigator text

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hey In react native I'm using  and  Everything works well so far but the title and the back button text don't line up. (**The login is higher then register**) Any ideas how I could set this up?

[image]

```
render() {
    const titleConfig = {
      title: 'login',
      tintColor: "white",
    }
    return(
        <View style={styles.bb}>
            <NavigationBar
              title={titleConfig}
              tintColor="black" />
        </View>

    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in a react element to title prop with styling to make it align as per your requirements. For e.g:

```
render() {
  const title = <View style={styles.navTitle}>
    <Text style={styles.navTitleText}>Login</Text>
  </View>;

  return (
    <View style={styles.bb}>
       <NavigationBar
          title={title}
          tintColor="black"
        />
    </View>
  );
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  navTitleText: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 19,
    marginBottom: 4,
  }
});
```

Here's the complete guide about the API https://github.com/react-native-fellowship/react-native-navbar#api